# PowerShell script - Loop list of folders to get file count and sum of files for each folder listed

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to get the file count & the sum of files for each individual folder listed in DGFoldersTEST.txt.
However, I’m currently getting the sum of all 3 folders.
And now I'm getting '***Index was outside the bounds of the array***' error message.

```
$DGfolderlist = Get-Content -Path C:\DiskGroupsFolders\DGFoldersTEST.txt

$FolderSize =@() 
$int=0

Foreach ($DGfolder in $DGfolderlist)
{
$FolderSize[$int] = 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $DGfolderlist -File -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | 
    Select-Object -Property Count, @{Name='Size(MB)'; Expression={('{0:N2}' -f($_.Sum/1mb))}}

Write-Host $DGfolder
Write-Host $FolderSize[$int]
$int++
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain the error, you're trying to assign a value at index `$int` of your `$FolderSize` array, however, when arrays are initialized using the [array subexpression operator `@(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--), they're intialized with **0 [Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=net-6.0#system-array-length)**, hence why the error. It's different as to when you would initialize them with a specific Length:

```
$arr = @()
$arr.Length       # 0
$arr[0] = 'hello' # Error

$arr = [array]::CreateInstance([object], 10)
$arr.Length       # 10
$arr[0] = 'hello' # all good
```

As for how to approach your code, since you don't really know how many items will come as output from your loop, initializing an array with a specific Length is not possible. PowerShell offers the [`+=` operator for adding elements to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#manipulating-an-array), however this **is a very expensive operation** and not a very good idea because each time we append a new element to the array, **a new array has to be created**, this is because [**arrays are of a fixed size**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-add?view=net-6.0#remarks). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708578/why-should-i-avoid-using-the-increase-assignment-operator-to-create-a-colle) for more information and better approaches.

You can simply let PowerShell capture the output of your loop by assigning the variable to the loop itself:

```
$FolderSize = foreach ($DGfolder in $DGfolderlist) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $DGfolder -File -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum | 
        Select-Object @(
            @{ Name = 'Folder'; Expression = { $DGfolder }}
            'Count'
            @{ Name = 'Size(MB)'; Expression = { ($_.Sum / 1mb).ToString('N2') }}
        )
}
```